# Where Postgres database files are saved in ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

How can I find where Postgres 8.x database files are saved in Ubuntu 10.04 file system?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the postgres prompt, just execute this query:

```
SHOW data_directory;
```

Check also the Ubuntu manual:
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postgresql.html

Comment: Do i need to execute the SHOW command from the postgres prompt?

Comment: Execute this query just like you execute all queries. You could use pgAdmin, psql or whatever client you use. But, why do you need these files? And did you read the Ubuntu manual?

Comment: @FrankHeikens: I got a question: if a user can access the postgres database files, can they extract the database structure or other information from those files? Thanks.

Comment: SHOW data_directory;
after running above command, it is giving me the result below. What does it mean?

        data_directory        
------------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
(1 row)

Comment: @TaimoorChangaiz Uh, it means the data files are stored at  /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main

Comment: @ShangWang Yes, if a user has permission to read the database files, there's information that could be gleaned from examining them. They'd have to be fairly sophisticated to figure out the database structure, but if your DB contains sensitive data, then the files should not be readable by anyone other than the user under which postgresql runs.

Answer (score 7):

**Here's how I located the directory of my Postgres database files in Ubuntu:**

Run the command below in your terminal to switch user to `postgres` user:

```
su - postgres
```

It will request for the `postgres` user **password** which you set up when you were setting up PostgreSQL on your machine.

Next, you will need to login into the `psql` terminal/prompt. This can be accomplished by running the code below:

```
psql
```

It will also request for the `postgres` **password** which you set up when you were setting up PostgreSQL on your machine.

If you are successfully logged in, you will see a prompt similar to this:

```
psql (11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-3.pgdg18.04+1), server 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-1.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

At this point you will execute the query below to display the directory where Postgres Database files are stored on your Linux macchine:

```
SHOW data_directory;
```

This should display an output similar to this:

```
data_directory        
-----------------------------
/var/lib/postgresql/10/main
(1 row)
```

You can now locate the Postgres Database files by navigating the directory that was displayed.

However, the PostgreSQL configuration directory in Ubuntu is located in `/etc/postgresql/10/main`. Take note that `10` is the version of my PostgreSQL installation on my server. Your version might be `9.5`, `11` or `12` or any other version. Run the command `psql --version` to confirm your PostgreSQL version.

Run the command below to navigate to the directory:

```
cd ~
cd /etc/postgresql/10/main
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**