# Where is the database file? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm newbie in Rails and I just finished one part of the app I'm developing and I'm wondering where is the database file, I cannot found it on the rails.root directory. Does anyone has the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm searching the file not the configuration file and I'm using PostgreSQL and Ubuntu

Comment: "database file" doesn't mean much with PostgreSQL. If you want to copy the database then you'll want to dump/restore rather than trying to copy a file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The database **configuration** file is in `config/database.yml`.

If you're using `sqlite`, the database itself is in `db/` folder.

You may want to read [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) for more info.

Edit: For PostgreSQL, you can execute `SHOW data_directory` in `psql` to find the database files location.

Edit (CR): Note that you can't just *copy* the data directory though. Read [the PostgreSQL manual on backup and restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html) for how to copy your database correctly.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/197626/where-is-a-postgresql-9-1-database-stored-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: The `database.yml` file describes database names and login information, etc, but it doesn't give the paths for actual database files usually. Those are maintained by the database program.

Comment: @mbratch True, I'm not sure if the OP is asking for the actual db file itself (which depends on the database), or just the location of the `database.yml` file...

Comment: Hi, I'm searching for the database file, not the databse.yml

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 13.04, database PostgreSQL

Comment: @MarcPursals [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467167/where-postgres-database-files-are-saved-in-ubuntu) should help you.

Comment: @user2062950 indeed. I think your answer provides good information. I was taking the OP's question at face value, but it could be they mean configuration, not the database itself.

Answer (score 3):

With postgres, there is no db file in the db directory, like with sqlite3, e.g development.sqlite3, test.sqlite3.  However, there will be a migration in db/migrate.  rails uses the information in the config/database.yml file to connect to postgres, and then your data is stored in postgres, i.e. outside your app.  For instance, in the Postgres/9.2/data directory.

I just got through installing postgres locally for use with rails, and I wrote up everything I did in two posts, which might prove useful to you.  See here:

[How do I get my rails app to use my postgresql db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094845/how-do-i-get-my-rails-app-to-use-my-postgresql-db)

[How do I start enterpiseDB PostgreSQL on Mac OSX 10.6.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971101/how-do-i-start-enterpisedb-postgresql-on-mac-osx-10-6-8)

ubuntu is Linux and Mac OSX is built on top of unix, so they are similar.  Your postgres install directory, however, will be different than mine, so make note of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are  using sqlite you run rake db:create it will be under

`RAILS_ROOT/db/development.sqlite3`

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends upon what database program you are using. Rails doesn't manage the location of the database files, but the database program does.

In MySQL for example, they are under `/var/lib/mysql` on Fedora.